# How to create a local server to compile and run programs in C, Java,..etc

Tags: java, webserver, compile, ubuntu-server, c

How can I create a local server on my Ubuntu laptop which is able to compile and run C, Java, 
Ruby, Python, etc code?

And I want to use that service from my tablet through WiFi.

Comment: confusing.... "local server" ??? web server? you want to run web apps/scripts? and compile c/java or run cgi?

Comment: local server which can be accessable through a tablet to  compile and run scripts in c, Java @Logman

Comment: there are hundreds of types of servers, you really did not clear anything up regarding your question above. Use it from you tablet? you mean the browser? There are dozens of ways to connect to a service from a tablet/wifi http/ftp/telnet/vnc/rdp/..etc... on and on... "compile" has nothing to do with a web server, and "c & java" are not scripts while Ruby/python are scripting languages for mainly web servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is a good starting point: [Installing Ubuntu 11.04 Server Natty Narwhal](http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/initial/OSInstall.php)

After installation of the server you will need to [prepare your system for building packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install cvs subversion git-core mercurial
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/src
sudo chmod u+rwx /usr/local/src
```

In the next steps you will surely want to install [LAMP](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LAMP) and run your own Web Server.
You can access your system and start the build from the tablet as well through [SSH(SecureShell)](http://linuxhomeserverguide.com/initial/SSH.php).

I've made a good experiences with [openSUSE Build Service](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_FAQ) (if you are not depend on Ubuntu).